# Spring Cloud DataFlow http polling and deduplication

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have been reading much Spring Cloud DataFlow and related documentation in order to produce a data ingest solution that will run in my organization's Cloud Foundry deployment.  The goal is to poll an HTTP service for data, perhaps three times per day for the sake of discussion, and insert/update that data in a PostgreSQL database.  The HTTP service seems to provide 10s of thousands of records per day.

One point of confusion thus far is a best practice in the context of a DataFlow pipeline for deduplicating polled records.  The source data do not have a timestamp field to aid in tracking polling, only a coarse day-level date field.  I also have no guarantee that records are not ever updated retroactively.  The records appear to have a unique ID, so I can dedup the records that way, but I am just not sure based on the documentation how best to implement that logic in DataFlow.  As far as I can tell, the [Spring Cloud Stream starters](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/) do not provide for this out-of-the-box.  I was reading about Spring Integration's [smart polling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#conditional-pollers), but I'm not sure that's meant to address my concern either.

My intuition is to create a custom Processor Java component in a DataFlow Stream that performs a database query to determine whether polled records have already been inserted, then inserts the appropriate records into the target database, or passes them on down the stream.  Is querying the target database in an intermediate step acceptable in a Stream app?  Alternatively, I could implement this all in a Spring Cloud Task as a batch operation which triggers based on some schedule.

What is the best way to proceed with respect to a DataFlow app?  What are common/best practices for achieving deduplication as I described above in a DataFlow/Stream/Task/Integration app?  Should I copy the setup of a starter app or just start from scratch, because I am fairly certain I'll need to write custom code?  Do I even need Spring Cloud DataFlow, because I'm not sure I'll be using its DSL at all?  Apologies for all the questions, but being new to Cloud Foundry and all these Spring projects, it's daunting to piece it all together.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, given your requirements you will most likely need to create a custom processor. You need to keep track of what has been inserted in order to avoid duplication.

There's nothing preventing you from writing such processor in a stream app, however performance may take a hit, since for each record you will issue a DB query.

If order is not important, you could parallelize the query so you could process several concurrent messages, but in the end your DB would still pay the price.

Another approach would to use a [bloomfilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) that can help quite a lot on speeding up your checking for inserted records.

You can start by cloning the starter apps, you could have a poller trigger an http client processor that fetches your data and then go through your custom code processor and finally to a jdbc-sink. Something like `stream create time --triger.cron=<CRON_EXPRESSION> | httpclient --httpclient.url-expression=<remote_endpoint> | customProcessor | jdbc`

One of the advantages of using SCDF is that you could independently scale your custom processor via deployment properties such as `deployer.customProcessor.count=8`

Comment: Also see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud Data Flow builds integration streams for data based on the Spring Cloud Stream, which, in turn, is fully based on the Spring Integration. And all the principles exist in Spring Integration can be applied everywhere there on the SCDF level.

That really might be a case that you won't be able to avoid some codding, but what you need is called in EIP [Idempotent Receiver](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/IdempotentReceiver.html). And [Spring Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#idempotent-receiver) provides one for us:

```
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "processChannel")
    @IdempotentReceiver("idempotentReceiverInterceptor")
    public void handle(Message<?> message)
```